# Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing in SSH logs

Tags: ssh, debian, security, logging, ftp

I found this logs in my auth.log

```
Apr 21 03:36:10 mikigal sshd[18181]: Accepted password for mikigal from MY_HOME_IP_ADRESS port 51814 ssh2
Apr 21 03:36:10 mikigal sshd[18181]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user mikigal by (uid=0)
Apr 21 03:36:10 mikigal systemd-logind[682]: New session 11 of user mikigal.
Apr 21 03:36:11 mikigal sshd[18189]: Received disconnect from MY_HOME_IP_ADRESS port 51814:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing
Apr 21 03:36:11 mikigal sshd[18189]: Disconnected from MY_HOME_IP_ADRESS port 51814
Apr 21 03:36:11 mikigal sshd[18181]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user mikigal
Apr 21 03:36:11 mikigal systemd-logind[682]: Removed session 11.
```

These logs exist on random hour, always from my IP address. At hours of this logs my PC was turned off. I reinstalled sytem on my VPS yesterday, because i thought I have some malware on my server, but logs still exists.

last command output:

```
mikigal  pts/1        MY_HOME_IP_ADRESS  Sat Apr 21 12:37   still logged in
mikigal  pts/1        MY_HOME_IP_ADRESS  Sat Apr 21 11:35 - 12:15  (00:39)
mikigal  pts/1        MY_HOME_IP_ADRESS  Sat Apr 21 04:20 - 04:22  (00:01)
mikigal  pts/1        MY_HOME_IP_ADRESS  Sat Apr 21 04:04 - 04:05  (00:00)
mikigal  pts/1        MY_HOME_IP_ADRESS  Sat Apr 21 04:04 - 04:04  (00:00)
mikigal  pts/0        MY_HOME_IP_ADRESS  Sat Apr 21 03:15 - 04:16  (01:01)
root     pts/0        MY_HOME_IP_ADRESS  Sat Apr 21 03:07 - 03:14  (00:06)
reboot   system boot  4.9.0-6-amd64    Sat Apr 21 03:07   still running
root     pts/0        MY_HOME_IP_ADRESS  Sat Apr 21 03:04 - down   (00:02)
reboot   system boot  4.9.0-3-amd64    Sat Apr 21 03:04 - 03:07  (00:03)

wtmp begins Sat Apr 21 03:04:01 2018
```

Login at 03:36:11 from auth.log does not exists in last output. There is no info about this login in fail2ban.log. I have Debian 9. System and packets are updated to the newest version.

Is this normal? I have install fail2ban, disabled root login, custom SSH/SFTP port.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably SFTP or SCP sessions: the OpenSSH `sshd` doesn't recognize them as interactive sessions and won't log them into `/var/log/wtmp` the `last` commend reads. The `Normal Shutdown` is from `sshd` and the `Thank you for playing` is a message sent by the client on clean shutdown. There's nothing suspicious in the content of these log lines by themselves.

Fail2Ban wouldn't work here, because

- it's not some random IP address but your IP, which could even be whitelisted
- it's a successful connection: no fail, no ban.

Could there be some kind of automated backup on any device on your home network?

The connection uses password authentication. Have you tried changing your password?

Comment: Only my PC have access to this server, only I have this password. This logs exists on time, when I'm in school so my PC is always turned off. No, I'm not changed my password. Should I change it?

Comment: It is straight because are only in the newest auth.log, there are not exists in auth.log.1.gz, auth.log.2.gz etc.